# May trees be reused

Tags: scala, macros, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm writing a macros and need the same statement appear in different places. Should I define that statement as `val` or `def`?

`val` seems natural, but I'm afraid that `Tree` may have mutable internal realization (e.g. storing line number) and reusing the same value in different places may bring chaos.

May I reuse the same object, or should I produce new object each time? What about existing `Tree`? Can I safely disassemble it and use its parts for creating another `Tree`?